# Prevent manually added data from shifting rows in auto-updating google sheet

Tags: google-sheets, automation

[Link to test file](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1I6-tV336C1CJ6Spd-k_WdXBnGuKDyGo_R2onIGGZ324/edit?usp=sharing)

In my test file, I have two sheets.
1.
[image]
^ First one represent automatic data which will be later on fetched from auto-updating place like salesforce.

2.
[image]
^Second one has automatic data in first two columns and manually added data in third

3.
[image]
^The problem is that whenever new data is added by the automatic sheet (John in this case)

4.
[image]
^Then all automatic data gets pushed down but manually added data stays in its initial cells - do you have any idea how I can fix manual cells to follow the automatic data that they were added to?

+ **yes** I need the newest data to appear on top to address the discoverability issue there will be a lot of entries in the final file

Any help appreciated

Comment: Welcome to [Web Applications Stack Exchange](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/tour).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are manually adding data side-by-side with dynamically inserted data. As you have noticed, this exposes you to the risk of rows getting misaligned.

Lance has given a thorough [treatment of the row misalignment issue](https://support.google.com/docs/thread/95901649) and how it can be dealt with in some cases.